Clarification: Probability spaces with same sample space and different event spaces
Just to say, I am aware of the existence of this question but I do not think it really answers the question/clarification I have in mind.
Also, this question mostly requests confirmation that I am not mistaken on a very basic notion, so it may not warrant a long reply (or even any formal reply at all besides a 'yes' or 'no' in the comments).
A probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a structure comprising the set $\Omega$ of all the possible outcomes of a random experiment (the sample space), a set $\mathcal{F}$ of (measurable) events from $\Omega$ (event space) to which we are going to assign a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.
That events must be measurable means that $\mathcal{F}$ must be a $\sigma$-algebra. This is often justified as being necessary for continuous random variables and useful when considering a stochastic process (coin tossing over time is a common example) or the event space ($\sigma$-algebra) induced by a a random variable.
In the case of a discrete sample space, one often just identifies the event space to be the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ of $\Omega$.
Now, beyond the aforementioned cases where the use of a $\sigma$-algebra might be necessary, I am interested in clarifying how one can build multiple valid event spaces (that make sense) for a simple discrete sample space.
For example, take a 6-sided die with sample space $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.
We may consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_1, \mathbb{P}_1)$ where $\mathcal{F}_1 = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
But we could also consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_2, \mathbb{P}_2)$ where $\mathcal{F}_2 = \{\emptyset, \{1,3,5\}, \{2,4,6 \}, \Omega \}$ which, in practice, may correspond to only caring about whether the outcome is even or odd.
Would this be a correct way of thinking of different probability spaces with the same sample space but different event spaces?

Yes, it is. Looking at the wiki definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space, Definition section, your example fits: it contains the sample space and it is closed under complement and union.
